# Select positions of points in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I am trying to attach some instances (of a sphere) on some specific points of a disc mesh (say some specific points on the top portion of this disc) using geometry nodes. Is there any way to attach these instances?, Right now these points are chosen randomly via point distribute node.
Thank You

Comment: You could use vertex groups…and put this vertex groups in selection of Point instance node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e.g. you want only to distribute on this points: -> create a vertex group for them

[image: 2.56319 m]

and use this node setup:

[image]

and you got:

[image]

Note: this is a solution for Blender 3.0alpha

Comment: Thanks alot @Chris

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you.